# Automatically include header files when I open a .c file

Tags: c, unix, gcc, vim, stdio

I want to know if this is possible...

Whenever we want to compile a C program or C++ etc, we need some to include header files like #include in .c file....

Is there any way so that, any file which gets created by some name.c, will automatically include the header file without typing in the program... I'm not sure how this works...

Or even something like this...i use vim, so if I save any file like a.c, (without putting #include in the program), the vim or gcc, whichever, considers this as .c file and adds the stdio.h file..I don't mean that it should add in the program, but while compiling it should take stdio.h file also...Is this possible...?

Comment: think you might not be understanding what is happening, otherwise a bit of thinking about it would tell you that, no, you can't.

Comment: yes i gave it a thought and i know it wouldn't be possible....but you all have very good knowledge...So just wanted to know from you if this is really not possible..

Comment: maybe you don't want to write `int main(void)` later

Answer (score 4):

GCC [has](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) the `-include` option which allows you to do that. However, this feature is targeted at a different use case and IMHO what you are suggesting is not a good idea. Just write your `#include` directives in the source, you only need to do this once.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have to specify the `#include` in the implementation file is to tell the compiler which functionality you actually want. A function name is just a name, and though certain functions like `fprintf()` can be associated with a particular functionality, other stuff (how about generic names like `remove()`, `create()`, `trigger()`) certainly can't. It's **your** job to specify this, and in C, this is done via the combination of `#include` and include paths. This is common to most programming languages; for example, in Java you have `import` and the classpath.

So, it's obviously a bad idea to leave the includes out. Now, if you're complaining about the effort to look this up and type it, try a snippet solution for Vim or use a full-fledged IDE, most of which offer handy shortcuts for this.

Answer (score 0):

using an sh script you may create a global variable containing the file name.

you can after use `gcc %tmp_file%.c -include %tmp_file%.h`